# Are the logical states of the corresponding unencoded state unique?

Tags: error-correction, stabilizer-code

Given the generators of a stabilizer code and this code's orthogonal projector is $\Pi$. Take five qubit code as am example, the logical state of $\vert 0 \rangle$ is calculated as $\vert 0^L \rangle = \Pi \vert 00000 \rangle$, where $\vert 0^L \rangle$ is the logical state of zero state. The question is whether the logical states of the corresponding unencoded state unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an $[\![n,k,d]\!]$ stabilizer code, with stabilizer generators $\langle S \rangle$ and $|S| = r$ i.e., there are $r$ different stabilizer generators, the total hilbert space of $n$ qubits, $\mathcal{H}$ of dimension $2^n$ is split into $2^r$ different orthogonal subspaces with each having $2^{n-r} = 2^k$ dimensions.

$$\mathcal{H} = \bigoplus_{J = 1}^{2^r}\mathbb{C}^{2^k} =\mathbb{C}^{2^n}\,.$$

Out of these different subspaces of $2^k$ dimension, only one subspace is our codespace ($+1$ eigenspace of all stabilizers), and the projector is on this codespace.

[image]

Now, consider unencoded states. Since you are working with $k$ qubits, your unencoded state would be of $k$ qubits and lie in a  $2^k$ dimensional space. Hence, as you can see, your unencoded Hilbert space of $k$ logical qubits and codespace of $n$ qubits have the exact dimensions $2^k$. There is no extra room. The mapping is bijective.

So, there is only one unique encoded state of $n$ qubits for a given physical state of $k$ qubits. (Of course, up to a global phase.)

Comment: Thank for this imformative picture!